# jQuery script for toggle only working twice

Tags: javascript, jquery, togglebutton

I'm trying to update a setting in my app when a toggle is clicked using the following script:

```
$(function() {
  $(".radio-switch").on('click', '#switch-units', function() {
    // $("input").prop('disabled', true);
    var currUnits = $("input[name='units']:checked").val();
    var units;
    alert(currUnits);

    if (currUnits === 'km') {
      $("input[id='km']").attr('checked', false);
      $("input[id='miles']").attr('checked', true);
      units = 'miles';
    } else if (currUnits === 'miles') {
      $("input[id='miles']").attr('checked', false);
      $("input[id='km']").attr('checked', true);
      units = 'km';
    }

    alert(units);
    var data = {
      username: '{{ username }}',
      units: units
    };
    alert(data.username);

    $.ajax({
      url: '/api/settings/units',
      type: 'POST',
      dataType: 'json',
      data: data,
      success: function(data) {
        // $("input").prop('disabled', false);
        if (data.status === 'saved') {
          // alert("units updated ! ");
        }
        if (data.status === 'invalid') {
          alert(data.message);
        }
      }
    });
  });
});
```

The script executes properly for the first two clicks and all my alerts return what you would expect. On the third click however, the `currUnits` and `units` variables both alert as `undefined`.

I can't figure out what the issue is and I was hoping somebody could point me in the right direction. Thanks in advance.

HTML template:

```
<span class="title">Units</span>
<div class="radio-switch">
  <input type="radio" name="units" value="km" id="km" class="active-left" {% if settings is not null and settings.units=="KM" %}checked="checked" {% endif %}>
  <input type="radio" name="units" value="miles" id="miles" {% if settings is null or settings.units=="MILES" %}checked="checked" {% endif %}>
  <label for="km">Km</label>
  <span id="switch-units" class="virtual-switch"></span>
  <label for="miles">Miles</label>
</div>
</span>
```

Comment: share your html code also

Comment: Will do so now, two seconds

Comment: Please only show the  code relevant to the specific problem as per [mcve]

Comment: Try the use of `.prop()` instead of `.attr()`.

Comment: @Louys that's solved it mate. Thank you, silly mistake really.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for set checked (or unchecked) use these syntaxes:

```
  $("input[id='km']").prop('checked', true/*or false*/);
```

or

```
  $("input[id='km']")[0].checked=true/*or false*/;
```